# mysql nodejs too many connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, runtime-error, database-connection

I have an API server which runs different API calls to a mysql database: this is the file which entirely handles the connections and the queries:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: sqlhost,
  port: sqlport,
  user: sqluser,
  password: sqlpsw,
  database: sqldb,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
  connectionLimit: 10
})

module.exports = {
  get: function (sqlQuery, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) reject(new Error(505))
        else {
          connection.query(sqlQuery, function (err, results) {
            connection.release()
            if (err !== null) reject(new Error(503))
            else resolve(results)
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

After some time I get the `Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections`.
I know i may have used pool.query instead of the flow pool.getConnection --> connection.query --> connection.release but the result is (I guess) the same.

I have no idea what is causing the "connections leak". Any idea? Thanks

Comment: If I could suggest something you could use knexJS which works really well (handles the release of connections for you for example). No idea what's wrong in your case though

Comment: It ended up being a database error, it was under ddos attack (not sure if it's the right attack name) so I solved it by moving to another host

Comment: Using pool.query or  pool.getConnection is really the same (i mean - pool.query uses pool.getConnection internally but it looks much better in your code). What the problem is - your database has small amount of connections available - you should lower the `connectionLimit` amount until the app is working correctly (or read mysql server setting - there should be variable stating how many connection might be active at once). Remember that mysql/mysql2 keeps as many connections as it is required (amd max === `connectionLimit`) but it do not open them at start but when needed until using the limit